# Getting the argument names along with values in a dynamic method invoke

Tags: c#, dynamic, dynamicobject, tryinvokemember

I am implementing a `DynamicObject`. In the `TryInvokeMethod`, in addition to the arguments ( passed in to the method), I also need the names for the parameters if they have been used.

I can see that `binder.CallInfo.ArgumentNames` does indeed provides the names, but I am not able to associate them with the values. Is there any way to do so, or am I hoping against hope:

```
public override bool TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, object[] args, out object result)
{
    var names = binder.CallInfo.ArgumentNames;
    foreach (var arg in args)
    {
        arguments.Add(new Argument(arg));
    }
    //I need to associate the names and the args
    result = this;
    return true;
}
```

So for example if I do a call like:

```
myDynamicObject.DynamicInvoke("test", something: "test2")
```

I have `test` and `test2`, and also `something`, but I am not able to get the information that `something` was the name for `test2` and `test` had no name.

Comment: You should assume that the last argument name if any corresponds to last method parameter and so on.

Comment: @user629926 thanks for the pointer. I used that to get the code below. You can still add as answer if you want and I will accept that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to use the fact that named arguments occur only after the non-named ones are specified ( thanks to [user629926](https://stackoverflow.com/users/629926/user629926) for pointing to the obvious) and initial code:

```
var names = binder.CallInfo.ArgumentNames;
var numberOfArguments = binder.CallInfo.ArgumentCount;
var numberOfNames = names.Count;

var allNames = Enumerable.Repeat<string>(null, numberOfArguments - numberOfNames).Concat(names);
arguments.AddRange(allNames.Zip(args, (flag, value) => new Argument(flag, value)));
```

Comment: One option to possibly simplify your code would be to use `var allNames = Enumerable.Repeat(null, numberOfArguments - numberOfNames).Concat(names);`. Then you can just use `Enumerable.Zip` to pair the values and the names, with `null` for unnamed arguments.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ah nice. I did refactor the code above, but this is neater.